# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I am using below query to return all the child elements and then based on child node i want to fetch the result.

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(@"E:\Samples\TestConsole\TestConsoleApp\TestConsoleApp\XMLFile1.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> lv1s = from lv1 in rootElement.Descendants("A")
                   where lv1.Attribute("Code").Value.Equals("A001") && lv1.Attribute("Lable").Value.Equals("A001")
                   select (from ltd in lv1.Descendants("A1")
                           where ltd.Attribute("Code").Value.Equals("001")
                           select ltd.Elements()).ToList();
```

But  still i am having following error.

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Please let me know.

i want my value of lv1s["A11"], lv1s["A22"]

below is my xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Document>
  <A Code="A001" Lable="A001">
    <A1 Code="001">
      <A11>A1</A11>
      <A22>A2</A22>
      <A33>A3</A33>
    </A1>
  </A>
  <A Code="A002" Label="A002">
    <A1 Code="002">
      <A44>A44</A44>
      <A55>A55</A55>
    </A1>
  </A>
</Document>
```

Please let me know.

Also How i can handle "Enumeration yielded no results" as count 0 in my return list since it's giving count>0 if this error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Result of query has type `IEnumerable<List<IEnumerable<XElement>>>`. But you are trying to assign it to `IEnumerable<XElement>`.  Why? Because for each `A` element you are selecting list of `A1` child elements. That gives you collection of lists.

You can use explicit result type to solve this issue. I.e. instead of `IEnumerable<XElement> lv1s` use `var lvls`. Or use actual lvls type: `IEnumerable<List<IEnumerable<XElement>>> lvls`.

Or if you want to get `IEnumerable<XElement>` then use `SelectMany`:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> lv1s = 
    rootElement.Descendants("A")
               .Where(lv1 => (string)lv1.Attribute("Code") == "A001" &&
                             (string)lv1.Attribute("Lable") == "A001")
               .SelectMany(lv1 => lv1.Descendants("A1")
                            .Where(ltd => (string)ltd.Attribute("Code") == "001")
                            .Select(ltd => ltd.Elements());
```

Or rewrite your query this way:

```
   IEnumerable<XElement> lv1s =  
         from lv1 in rootElement.Descendants("A")
         where (string)lv1.Attribute("Code") == "A001" &&
               (string)lv1.Attribute("Lable") == "A001"
         from ltd in lv1.Descendants("A1")
         where (string)ltd.Attribute("Code") == "001"
         from e in ltd.Elements()
         select e;
```

Returns following elements:

```
  <A11>A1</A11>
  <A22>A2</A22>
  <A33>A3</A33>
```

Answer (score 1):

A suggestion: Instead of using `.Value`, cast as a `string`. Also, if your variable is in any case an `IEnumerable<XElement>` and not a `List<XElement>`, why do you need `ToList`?

```
XElement rootElement = XElement.Load(@"E:\Samples\TestConsole\TestConsoleApp\TestConsoleApp\XMLFile1.xml");
IEnumerable<XElement> lv1s = 
    from lv1 in rootElement.Descendants("A")
    where (string)lv1.Attribute("Code") == "A001" && (string)lv1.Attribute("Lable") == "A001"
    select (
        from ltd in lv1.Descendants("A1")
        where (string)ltd.Attribute("Code") == "001"
        select ltd.Elements()
    );
```

You have a nested LINQ query, and your query is also returning an `IEnumerable<XElement>`. Try removing the nested query, and returning a single element as the result of the query (the parentheses are only added for clarity):

```
IEnumerable<XElement> lv1s = (
    from lv1 in rootElement.Descendants("A")
    where (string)lv1.Attribute("Code") == "A001" && (string)lv1.Attribute("Lable") == "A001"
    from ltd in lv1.Descendants("A1")
    where (string)ltd.Attribute("Code") == "001"
    from e in ltd.Elements()
    select e
);
```

Also, if you are only searching one level deep, you can use `Elements` instead of `Descendants`:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> lv1s = (
    from lv1 in rootElement.Elements("A")
    where (string)lv1.Attribute("Code") == "A001" && (string)lv1.Attribute("Lable") == "A001"
    from ltd in lv1.Elements("A1")
    where (string)ltd.Attribute("Code") == "001"
    from e in ltd.Elements()
    select e
);
```

And if all you want are the **values** of those elements -- `A1`,`A2` and `A3` -- instead of `XElement` objects:

```
IEnumerable<string> lv1s = (
    from lv1 in rootElement.Elements("A")
    where (string)lv1.Attribute("Code") == "A001" && (string)lv1.Attribute("Lable") == "A001"
    from ltd in lv1.Elements("A1")
    where (string)ltd.Attribute("Code") == "001"
    from e in ltd.Elements()
    select (string)e
);
```